# Can't undo discard with atom (git) and ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, sqlite, atom-editor

I'm working with Atom and Git in a Ruby on Rails project. Unfortunately today I discarded changes on my development.sqlite3 database. I tried to recover via "Undo Discard" but was not successful. A merge conflict appears and the Atom console says:

> GitError: git -c color.ui=false -c color.status=false -c
>   color.showBranch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.branch=false
>   merge-file -p db/development.sqlite3
>   /private/var/folders/4r/4dj62r992jd05pwt8y9h29jw0000gn/T/github-discard-history-118028-13442-17wmext.0ll9ykfbt9/db/development.sqlite3-after-discard
>   /private/var/folders/4r/4dj62r992jd05pwt8y9h29jw0000gn/T/github-discard-history-118028-13442-17wmext.0ll9ykfbt9/db/development.sqlite3-before-discard -L current -L after discard -L before discard in /Users/xxx exited with code 255 stdout: 
>   stderr: error: Cannot merge binary files: db/development.sqlite3
>
> ```
> at new GitError (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/github/lib/git-shell-out-strategy.js:104:24)
> at /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/github/lib/git-shell-out-strategy.js:362:33
> at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> at step (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/github/lib/git-shell-out-strategy.js:92:197)
> at /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/github/lib/git-shell-out-strategy.js:92:367
> ```
>
> (anonymous) @ :104770 step @ :104089 (anonymous) @
>   :104089

Is there any possibility to rescue my last state? I know that rails db and merging conflicts are a special thing but I hope to get rid of it. I don't want to loose hours of work.

Thanks.

Comment: What's happening if you are actually trying to deal with your conflict via a command line ?

Comment: I'm quite new to git. What should I write into the command line?

Comment: I'd suggest you to first learn how GIT basically works. This won't be wasted time as it will always be useful (even if you are using an abstraction with your editor).

Comment: I know the basics but that's too special. I also searched for "Git undo discard" but didn't get a helpful result.

Comment: Well as I understand this, it seems like Atom is having some trouble rollbacking your changes rollback (yeah it's tricky) because it's a binary file. What I would so is first understand what this "Undo discard" does. If it is supposed to revert a commit, then maybe you can consider revert this commit with the command line.